# What's the fastest way to clone a Linux installed computer?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, clone

We have several same branded/model computers and would like to clone Linux-Mint repetitively for each one of them.
It takes about 1 hour to install/upgrade etc. for one computer.

What's the fastest way to clone for this situation?

Comment: Consider using CloneZilla LiveCD

Comment: What type and size drive does it have, how many clones do you need to make and how is it partitioned?

Comment: @davidgo There is no partition. The computers have Intel i3, 4 GB RAM, classic harddrive. We need about 20 clones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is probably using the built-in Timeshift app on Linux Mint.

You need a USB drive, preferably with at least 16 GB of space. Format it and create a Timeshift backup of one machine. Make sure to add your required directories while doing so, and then create the backup.

Once that is done, just restore the USB backup on all other identical machines you need to clone your setup on to. You need to have Linux Mint pre-installed on those systems. Finally, you can plug in your USB and restore each system using Timeshift.

Here's a fully detailed guide on how to use Timeshift: https://linuxhint.com/timeshift_linux_mint_19_usb/